# How to pass null as parameter in JUnit @Parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, null, junit4

Hi I'm passing 3 arguments to a test case using @Parameters annotation. It is possible to make any of the one as null and test? Please help..

Answer (score 4):

Which version of JUnit are you using? What's the problem if you simply try to return a null from the method with @Parameters annotation? Is it a NullPointerException? Because if so I remember there was such a bug in 4.10 don't know if they fixed it already.

Did you simply try returning `new Object[] {null, someObject1, someObject2}`? This should work. If not then please provide more information on how your test looks/what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

recently i started [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. it lets you write:

```
@TestWith({
   "25 USD, 7",
   "38 GBP, 2",
   "null,   0"
})
public void testMethod(Money money, int anotherParameter) {
   ...
}
```